# When is a left or right invertible morphism between isomorphic objects an isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I just happened upon the age-old question in the title. We all know that an injection or surjection between e.g. finite-dimensional vector spaces of the same dimension or finite sets of the same cardinality is automatically bijective.

Formulating it in an arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$, this property reads

> If $A, B \in \mathcal{C}$ are isomorphic and $l \colon A \to B$ (or $r \colon A \to B$) has a left (right) inverse, then $l$ ($r$) is an isomorphism.

or, more invariant,

> In $\mathcal{C}$, split epimorphisms (monomorphisms) between isomorphic objects are isomorphisms.

**Question 1:**
Are there some nice (general) properties of $\mathcal{C}$ for these statements to be true?

But maybe I don't want this property for the whole category, it's a bit strong.
Maybe I only want some "pointwise" thing like

> In $\mathcal{C}$, split epimorphisms (monomorphisms) between isomorphic objects satisfying property $P$ are isomorphisms.

Which leads to

**Question 2:**
What would property $P$ be, depending on $\mathcal{C}$?

A possible choice for $P$, which is informed by $\operatorname{Vect}$, could be:
if $\mathcal{C}$ is monoidal, then an object satisfies property $P$ iff it is dualizable.

---

*Edit:*
Of course, I do not assume $P$ to be unique in any way, and full disclosure: I didn't prove if "dualizability" really provides an answer to my question.

Comment: This is basically Dedekind-finiteness in general categories. I'm not sure it's studied much outside the context of set theory.